# Index notation with four-gradient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, notation

Reading Schwarz's textbook on quantum field theory, early on he gives the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-A_{\mu}J_{\mu}.$$
With $F^{\mu\nu}=(\partial_{\mu}A^{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A^{\mu})$, he simplies the Lagrangian to 
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})^2+\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}A_{\mu})^2-A_{\mu}J_{\mu}.$$
I tried to do the working to get to this point,
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}&=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-A_{\mu}J_{\mu}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\left[\Big(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\Big)\Big(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\Big)\right]-A_{\mu}J_{\mu}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\left[\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}+\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\Big(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\Big)+\frac{1}{4}\Big(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}+\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}\Big)-A_{\mu}J_{\mu}.
\end{align*}
I can see how the first term is obviously $-1/2(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})^2$, but I can't see how the second term simplifies to $1/2(\partial_{\mu}A_{\mu})^2$. Do we just let $\mu \leftrightarrow \nu$, or something else?

Comment: Be careful in distinguishing between upper and lower indices.

Comment: Schwartz stated at the outset that there wasn't much need to make the distinction in quantum field theory.

Comment: Hint: integration by parts